# How to find a polynomial expression for $\ln(x)^{i}$, where $x>0$, and $i \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \setminus \{1\}$?

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponentiation

Seems a bit difficult since, even if it possible to say:

$\displaystyle \forall \,\, 0 < a < 1,\,\, \ln(a) \,= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(a-1)^n}{n}$

$\displaystyle \forall  \,\, a > 1,\,\, \ln(a) \,= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)^n$

If you power up the logarithm, it may not end in an infinite Newton power sum expression development, since the power series expressing the logarithm is an infinite sum...

There must be other ways.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Do you want a closed form for the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\ln(x)^i$ about $x=1$?

Comment: A polynomial expression of $\ln(x)^{i}$ for all $x>0, i \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \backslash \{1\}$

Comment: It's not a polynomial in any case.

Comment: Well I found one...

Comment: Check the definition of polynomial.

Comment: no need to check any definition. Check the multiplication...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like
$$\ln(x)^i = i! \sum_{n=i}^\infty s(n,i) \frac{(x-1)^n}{n!} $$
for positive integers $i$ and $|x-1|<1$, where $s(n,i)$ are (signed) [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

EDIT:
Then also

$$ \ln(x)^i = (-1)^{n+i} \ln(1/x)^i = (-1)^i i! \sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{s(n,i)}{n!} \left( \frac{x-1}{x}\right)^n $$
for $|(x-1)/x| < 1$, which covers $x > 1$.

Comment: I need a "on all $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$" answer.

Comment: Anyway my last comment, how did you get this result Robert, please?

Comment: See formula (12) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html).